# Porcentagem de ganhar em PHP

Tags: php, porcentagem

Olá, estou criando um sistema de itens no meu site. Cada item tem uma certa chance de ganhar.

Por exemplo, **0.01%**

Gostaria de saber como fazer para o PHP toda vez que o usuario jogar, tente ganhar algum item com essa porcentagem.

Tipo assim:

```
if(drop_item(0.01) == true) {
    echo "Você ganhou uma poção!";
} else {
    echo "Você não ganhou nada!";
}
```

Se souberem como fazer isso com multiplos itens, com cada item com uma chance de ganhar, ficaria muito feliz :)

Obrigado pela atenção.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [`rand()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php) passando um valor mínimo e máximo:

```
echo mt_rand(1, 10000); // Mostra um número entre 1 e 10000, por exemplo, 2634
```

Se não me engano 0.01% é 1 chance a cada 10000, então:

```
if(mt_rand(1, 10000) === 1) {
    echo "Você ganhou uma poção!";
} else {
    echo "Você não ganhou nada!";
}
```

---

Você pode fazer uma função que receba essa porcentagem e converta:

```
function sortear($porcentagem) {
    return mt_rand(1, 100 / $porcentagem) === 1;
}

if(sortear(0.01)) {
    echo "Você ganhou uma poção!";
} else {
    echo "Você não ganhou nada!";
}
```

A função já retorna true ou false

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu posso fazer essa conversão da porcentagem para o número (que nesse caso ficou 10000)?

Comment: No caso você precisa passar um numero em % e retornar o valor máximo?

Comment: Acho que sim. Eu estou guardando os itens em uma array, e nessa array eu gostaria de botar o valor de chance de ganhar em % para uma melhor vizualização, caso eu precise mudar alguma coisa depois.

Comment: Editei a resposta, acredito que é mais ou menos o que precisa

Comment: Faltou o 0, e também errei que é divisão e não multiplicação

Comment: Agora só esta retornando que a pessoa ganhou XD

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79005/discussion-between-dante-and-guilherme-costamilam).